# What is the purpose of the [active] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, meta-tags

A pretty simple discussion-style question for those that know more about the [apparently] relevant technologies than I do: what is the purpose of the [active](/questions/tagged/active) tag on Stack Overflow? Why does it exist in the first place, and should it continue to exist?

There's no tag wiki information, so it's all just guesses as to its intended purpose. If it *has* a purpose, creating this would be a good start.

There are a reasonable number of questions that currently carry this tag (582 at the time of this writing), so I don't feel comfortable making the unilateral decision to pursue its burnination.

But that number could be explained by inertia—the tag *exists*, so it is suggested/accepted for new questions/users, and thus people continue using it. But the real mind-boggler is that it has 20 followers. Who *follows* the "activity" tag? Who is an *expert* in the subject of activity/activities?

Comment: Just retag it [inactive].... that should do the job.

Comment: The one thing I *don't* think this tag is is a meta tag, @gnat. I mean, I guess people might interpret it that way, in a "I want this question to be active" sense. But I don't see it being used that way at all.

Comment: @CodyGray I feel it fits pretty well to what is written in [tag wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags): "...Alternatively, they may be ill-defined concepts which make consistent application of the tag difficult or impossible." As a reader, I would find it problematic to find out how "active" tag helps me identify question content

Answer (score 1):

The tag is being used for completely different and unrelated topics; in some cases, it is not even possible to understand to which *active* thing the tag is referring, since *active* is not used in the question text.

In some cases, the tag is added by users that select [active](/questions/tagged/active) instead of a more complete tag, which is what happens in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546759/active-directory-backward-visibility where [active](/questions/tagged/active) should be replaced by [active-directory](/questions/tagged/active-directory). In other cases, the tag is probably used by users who, instead of using an hyphenated tag that doesn't exist (and they are not allowed to create new tags), split the tag in two.

I would first check if the tag cannot be replaced by another *active** tag, replace it when it is possible, and then burninate the tag.